# Core animation failed to allocate bytes though NOT using Core Plot

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I get the following error on my iPod 4G and iPad 3 when I navigate through my app for some time, And the entire screen gets white OR the app Hangs and then I have to Restart the app.

```
CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 1879072 bytes
```

This issue generally comes when we use Core Plot, but I'm **NOT using Core Plot**

I'm **using ARC** in my code.

I've used MKMapview and CoreLocation for maps.

I did google for this issue but couldn't find anything except for core plot issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are using too much memory usage elsewhere in the app, and it's Core Animation that is first failing to make an allocation (particularly since it's a fairly large allocation). Run it through the "Allocations" tool in Instruments and investigate where you're using excessive memory.

Comment: @ Rob Napier : thanks for the rply.. I did check into Allocations.. It shows that my presentViewController methods with most allocations.. Any idea how I should go about that.??

Comment: What matters is what objects are being allocated. Then trace their usage and look for your mistake. Since you're using ARC, it is most likely that you're creating a retain loop somewhere. Check blocks you pass and make sure they're not capturing self. Think through where you believe these objects should be released. Perhaps you're caching something that is too large. Just remember: Instruments tells you where an object was allocated; it doesn't tell you where you forgot to get rid of it.